# Rounding down in python while keeping decimal points

Tags: python

I am writing a python program where it takes student names, IDs, and 3 exam scores using arrays and functions. I got the program down, but when it calculates the average of 3 exams, for example, `89`, `99`, and `90`. I need it to round down and output `92.0`. Instead it rounds to 93.0. I know how to round down, but then it doesn't show the decimal placement. Here's my code:

```
import math

def getStudentInfo(names,ids,score1,score2,score3):
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        names.append(input("Please enter a student's name : "))
        ids.append(int(input("Please enter the student's ID: ")))
        score1.append(float(input("Please enter first score: ")))
        score2.append(float(input("Please enter scond score: ")))
        score3.append(float(input("Please enter third score: ")))
        i = i+1

def updateStudentInfo(names,ids,score1,score2,score3):
    id = int(input("Please enter the ID of the student: "))
    if id in ids:
        i = ids.index(id)
    print("The student name is: " + names[i])
    print("ID is: " + str(ids[i]))
    print"First score  is:", int(score1[i])
    print"Second score  is:", int(score2[i])
    print"Third score  is:", int(score3[i])
    score1[i] = float(input("Please enter first score: "))
    score2[i] = float(input("Please enter Scond score: "))
    score3[i] = float(input("Please enter third score: "))

def displayStudentInfo(names,ids,score1,score2,score3):
    id = int(input("Please enter the ID of the student: "))
    if id in ids:
        i = ids.index(id)
        print("The student name is: " + names[i])
        print("ID is: " + str(ids[i]))
        print"First score  is:", int(score1[i])
        print"Second score  is:", int(score2[i])
        print"Third score  is:", int(score3[i])
    else:
        print("The ID is not found!")
        return

def calculateGrade(ids,score1,score2,score3):
    id = int(input("Please enter the ID of the student: "))
    if id in ids:
        i = ids.index(id)
    average = (score1[i] + score2[i] + score3[i]) / 3.0
    average = math.floor(average*100)/100
    if (average >= 90.0) and (average <= 100.0):
        grade = "A"
    elif (average >= 80.0) and (average <= 89.0):
        grade = "B"
    elif (average >= 70.0) and (average <= 79.0):
        grade = "C"
    elif (average >= 60.0) and (average <= 69.0):
        grade = "D"
    else:
        grade = "F"
    print"The average is:", average
    print("The grade is: " + grade)

def main():
    names = []
    ids    = []
    score1 = []
    score2 = []
    score3 = []
    while True:
        print("**** MENU OPTIONS ****")
        print("Type P to populate the student information.")
        print("Type U to update student Information")
        print("Type D to display the student information.")
        print("Type C to calculate the Grade.")
        print("Type E to exit")
        choice = input("Please enter your choice: ")
        if choice=="P":
            getStudentInfo(names,ids,score1,score2,score3)
        elif choice=="U":
            updateStudentInfo(names,ids,score1,score2,score3)
        elif choice=="D":
            displayStudentInfo(names,ids,score1,score2,score3)
        elif choice=="C":
            calculateGrade(ids,score1,score2,score3)
        elif choice=="E":
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In Python 2: `math.floor(x)`. In Python 3: `float(int(x))` or `float(math.floor(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the way you are calculating the average:

```
average = (score1[i] + score2[i] + score3[i]) / 3.0
average = math.floor(average*100)/100
```

The computer processes it in steps:

- Calculate the average: 92.66
- Take this number and multiple by 100: (89+99+90/3.0)*100 = 9266.6666...
- Then take the floor of 9266.666... which correctly gives 9266
- Divide 9266 by 100 giving 92.66
- 92.66 is rounded up to 93

If the scores are of type ints (i.e. 89 90 as opposed to 98% or .98 .89 or some other type) then you can simply do this:

```
average = math.floor((score1[i] + score2[i] + score3[i]) / 3.0)
```